# Extract values of integer from a table

Tags: r, integer

I have a dataframe with months and survival probability (SurvProb) as below

```
Months   SurvProb
23.9     100
24.3      99
26.5      98
27.0      98
28.1      97
28.9      94
30.3      90
..........
67       40
```

I would like to extract months beyond 24 with 1 month increment till 48 from the survival probability. The problem is that the dataframe does not always have months of the integral value. For example, the SurvProb value does not exist for month 24, but does for month 27. If this happens, I will then need the SurvProb of month that is the immediate smaller than the month of interest. Again, taking month 24 as an example, the SurvProb should be 100 as 23.9 is the immediate smaller one to 24.

The output should like this

```
24.0  100
25.0  99
26.0  99
27.0  98
........
48.0  xx
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not tested thoroughly, but `dat$SurvProb[findInterval(24:48, dat$Months)]` maybe?

Comment: Use `dput(SurvProb)` and paste the result into your question to provide reproducible data for testing possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else function to subset the data frame with minimum absolute difference between the value and the integer.

```
df <- structure(list(Months = c(23.9, 24.3, 26.5, 27, 28.1, 28.9, 30.3), 
                     SurvProb = c(100L, 99L, 98L, 98L, 97L, 94L, 90L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

out <- data.frame(Months = 24:48,
                  SurvProb = sapply(24:48, 
                                    function(x) 
                                      df[abs(df$Months-x) == min(abs(df$Months-x)), ]$SurvProb))
```

Output:

```
   Months SurvProb
1      24      100
2      25       99
3      26       98
4      27       98
5      28       97
6      29       94
7      30       90
8      31       90
9      32       90
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this finding the last row for each `ceiling` value, using tidyr's `complete` to insert the missing integer months, then `fill` to carry the previous values forward:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Months, ~SurvProb,
     23.9,      100L,
     24.3,       99L,
     26.5,       98L,
       27,       98L,
     28.1,       97L,
     28.9,       94L,
     30.3,       90L
  )

seq_needed <- seq(ceiling(min(df$Months)), ceiling(max(df$Months)), 1)

df |> 
  mutate(Months = ceiling(Months)) |> 
  group_by(Months) |> 
  slice_tail(n = 1) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  complete(Months = seq_needed) |> 
  fill(SurvProb)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   Months SurvProb
#>    <dbl>    <int>
#> 1     24      100
#> 2     25       99
#> 3     26       99
#> 4     27       98
#> 5     28       98
#> 6     29       94
#> 7     30       94
#> 8     31       90
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>